# TCP C Program Autoreconnect to client

Tags: c, tcp, tcpclient

I currently have a sensor located remotely connected using TCP. Problem is that the remote location keeps disconnecting, a scenario which i dont know how to rectify on my code. I have 3/10 idea of what im doing and most of the lines on this code is from internet.

**Question is, how do i implement a code that automatically reconnects to my tcp client?** tried a lot of methods but doesnt seem to work. The code however works perfectly provided connection is seamless.

```
#include <stdio.h> 
#include <netdb.h> 
#include <netinet/in.h> 
#include <stdlib.h> 
#include <string.h> 
#include <sys/socket.h> 
#include <sys/types.h> 
#include <time.h>
#define MAX 1000 
#define PORT 14344
#define SA struct sockaddr 

int main() 
{ 
        time_t t;
    time(&t);
    int sockfd, connfd, len; 
    struct sockaddr_in servaddr, cli; 
    unsigned char buff[MAX]; 
    int n,dd,a,b,c; 
    char timebuffer [80];
    time_t rawtime;
    struct tm * timeinfo;
    time ( &rawtime );
    timeinfo = localtime ( &rawtime );
        strftime (timebuffer,80,"/home/%m%d%y_%H%M%S",timeinfo);  
    FILE *fil1;
    fil1=fopen(timebuffer,"wb");

    printf("%s",ctime(&t));

    sockfd = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, 0); 
    if (sockfd == -1) { 
        printf("socket creation failed...\n"); 
        exit(0); } 
    else
        printf("Socket successfully created..\n"); 

    bzero(&servaddr, sizeof(servaddr)); 
    servaddr.sin_family = AF_INET; 
    servaddr.sin_addr.s_addr = htonl(INADDR_ANY); 
    servaddr.sin_port = htons(PORT); 

    if ((bind(sockfd, (SA*)&servaddr, sizeof(servaddr))) != 0) { 
        printf("socket bind failed...\n"); 
        exit(0); } 
    else    
    {
        printf("Socket successfully binded..\n"); 

        if ((listen(sockfd, 5)) != 0) { 
            printf("Listen failed...\n"); 
            exit(0); } 
        else
            printf("Server listening..\n");

        len = sizeof(cli); 

        connfd = accept(sockfd, (SA*)&cli, &len); 

        if (connfd < 0) { 
            printf("server accept failed...\n"); 
            exit(0); } 
        else    
            printf("server accepted...\n");

        while (1){
            bzero(buff, MAX); 
            dd=read(connfd, buff, sizeof(buff)); 
            printf("\n"); 

            for(a=0; a<=dd-1; a++){fprintf(fil1, "%c", buff[a]);printf("%02X", buff[a]);}

            printf("\n"); 
            bzero(buff, MAX);
            }
    }

        close(connfd);   
}
```

Comment: The code you posted is of socket server,it listens for incoming connections and reads from them, you should post code of tcp client that you want to fix

Comment: sorry. my client is a USRIOT device https://www.usriot.com/products/rs232-to-ethernet-converter.html I can only do it on my side to receive the data.

Comment: The server can't connect to the client. Only the client can connect to the server. So your question doesn't really make sense. Instead, you should probably be troubleshooting why the connection drops in the first place.

Comment: i see. its a satellite link because its too remote, and its weather dependent. Once there's bad weather or power outage the link dies and receiving it again need manual reactivation of the code above. THe sensor on the other side just keeps sending whenever possible. I tried UDP but I keep on losing vital packets so I moved to tcp. I was just wondering if theres a smarter way to receive tcp packets that just receives the data whether or not the link to the client was disconnected for a while. Just like UDP does

Comment: @JMF No, there is no automated reconnect mechanism for TCP. What you can try is to increase the timeouts on both sides to high values (see man 7 tcp)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You *must* send some data. If you do not send data, there is no guarantee that you can detect a lost connection. The only way you can reliably tell if the other end is still connected is if you try to send some data to it and it fails. Without trying, you have no way to know if the other end is there.

Next, you must check `read`'s return value. If there's an error, you need to close `connfd` and loop back to the `accept` call to get a new connection.

Comment: thank you david. I guess thats the best approach. I was thinking of using timer (since I know data intervals coming in, close and open manually), but checking read's return is better.

Comment: If you know that you will receive data at least every so often under normal circumstances, you could use a timer that causes you to `close` the connection if you have a connection open and don't receive data for sufficient time. I don't recommend this though, especially if your code will only try to `accept` a new connection after it has determined that an existing connection failed. The other side might realize it lost the connection long before you do, try to re-connect, and your code isn't going to call `accept` until much later.

Comment: hi David. I just added the read function in the while function to check incoming data and it worked. thank you very much.